# Javascript window onload in one file and dependent function and its call in another: order of execution

Tags: javascript

I have two Javascript files:

`drawField.js` and `updateState.js`

**drawField.js** has this call:

```
window.onload = function()  {
    drawField(10);
}
```

It creates an element `<div id="game-field">`.

In **updateState.js** file I make use of that element:

```
function getGameField()  {
    var gameDivs = document.getElementById("game-field").children;
    console.log(gameDivs);


}
getGameField();
```

However get an error: there are no children of element `null`.

If I place the `getGameField()` call inside `window.onload`, it works just fine. Which leads me to believe the call to the function gets executed before the `div` is created. Why would that be so? First, isn't the `onload` function supposed to be the first thing done once a page is loaded? Second, I have the first and second files imported like this into my page:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/drawField.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/updateState.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which made me believe that code in the `drawField.js` would get executed before code in `updateState.js`, which doesn't seem to be the case.

How would I fix this problem, without placing `getGameField()` call inside `window.onload`?

Comment: The 2 scripts do run in order, but `onload` gets pushed to the event queue and fires after the main page DOM gets loaded. That means `getGameField` fires before `onload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, isn't the  onload function supposed to be the first thing done once a page is loaded?

The page's `onload` event is fired after it gets *loaded*. Technically the page is considered loaded when all of its javascript files are loaded **and** executed in the browser. So when `updateState.js` file is executed, function `getGameField` is also executed, and when it searches for the element, it cannot find it since it hasn't been created yet.

> How would I fix this problem, without placing getGameField() call inside window.onload?

I would suggest placing `getGameField` in a callback if `window.onload` is not acceptable.

Comment: So basically `onload` is the last thing that would get executed? First, all of the files get loaded and executed, both the first and the second files, with the exception of the `onload` part of the first file. And only once that's done would the `onload` gets executed? Wow ;( I would guess then, it's better to just place `drawField` on the last line of the first file, since it isn't really dependent on the second file.

Comment: @parsecer You have mostly got it right. But putting that statement at the end of second file may not be equivalent to putting it in the callback of onload. If there are any other files to load, for example, there might be a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the logic method after creating tag:

```
window.onload = function()  {
  drawField(10);
  getGameField();
}
```

> First, isn't the onload function supposed to be the first thing done once a page is loaded?

Yes, but javascript may be executed before the page is fully loaded.

> Second, I have the first and second files imported like this into my page:
>   Which made me believe that code in the drawField.js would get executed before the code in updateState.js

That is correct, the code in `drawField.js` executed earlier, then the `updateState.js` executed. And then happened `onload` event which fired the method from the first file. So the method from the second file was executed (as you are calling it directly in the file) before the tag was created with `onload` event.

UPDATE:

You can also include your script files at the end of the body in needed order and immediate execution. Then you won't need an onload handler. This may not work for more difficult situations, though. Therefore, `onload` approach is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You have called the function getGameField() before the drawField() function. 
This is happening because the drawField() function is called when the document is completely loaded, where as the getGameField() function is called irrespective of the document status.

To solve this, call getGameField() function only when it is ensured that drawField() function is called before.